BTRFS Still showing errors after deleting files
BTRFS after running scrub gave the errors below.
I deleted the files under /xfs/backup_log/ which deleted all the debug.log files.
reran scrub and the errors were still there.
I then looked for the inodes with find / -inum and the inode wasn't found.
I then loaded a rescue disk so I could
btrfs check --repair -p /dev/md127
and it got stuck on [2/7] checking extents 406042
I eventually ran  iostat -xm 1 and found there was no disk activity so I stopped it.
I used an app on the rescue disk and it didn't get stuck but it didn't fix anything. The results of that are in the image.
Other than reinstall the system I don't what else I could do to fix these errors. Other files that it showed errors with already could not be found to delete.
btrfs check --repair result
[  255.269694] [    T127] BTRFS error (device md126): unable to fixup (regular) error at logical 4711251968 on dev /dev/md126 physical 4711251968
[  255.271004] [    T127] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711251968 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711251968, root 258, inode 2098687, offset 106496, length 4096, links 1 (path: lib/mysql-old/english_dev/field_data_field_basic_file_file.ibd)
[  255.271014] [    T127] BTRFS error (device md126): unable to fixup (regular) error at logical 4711251968 on dev /dev/md126 physical 4711251968
[  255.271038] [    T127] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711251968 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711251968, root 258, inode 2098687, offset 106496, length 4096, links 1 (path: lib/mysql-old/english_dev/field_data_field_basic_file_file.ibd)
[  255.271046] [    T127] BTRFS error (device md126): unable to fixup (regular) error at logical 4711251968 on dev /dev/md126 physical 4711251968
[  255.271066] [    T127] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711251968 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711251968, root 258, inode 2098687, offset 106496, length 4096, links 1 (path: lib/mysql-old/english_dev/field_data_field_basic_file_file.ibd)
[  255.271073] [    T127] BTRFS error (device md126): unable to fixup (regular) error at logical 4711251968 on dev /dev/md126 physical 4711251968
[  255.271108] [    T127] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711251968 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711251968, root 258, inode 2098687, offset 106496, length 4096, links 1 (path: lib/mysql-old/english_dev/field_data_field_basic_file_file.ibd)
[  255.271493] [    T127] BTRFS error (device md126): unable to fixup (regular) error at logical 4711907328 on dev /dev/md126 physical 4711907328
[  255.271634] [    T120] BTRFS error (device md126): unable to fixup (regular) error at logical 4711841792 on dev /dev/md126 physical 4711841792
[  255.273442] [    T117] BTRFS error (device md126): unable to fixup (regular) error at logical 4712366080 on dev /dev/md126 physical 4712366080
[  255.273689] [    T120] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711841792 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711841792, root 3138, inode 3313597, offset 0, length 4096, links 2 (path: usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/__pycache__/msvccompiler.cpython-36.opt-1.pyc)
[  255.273705] [    T120] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711841792 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711841792, root 3138, inode 3313597, offset 0, length 4096, links 2 (path: usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/__pycache__/msvccompiler.cpython-36.pyc)
[  255.274005] [    T120] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711841792 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711841792, root 3133, inode 3313597, offset 0, length 4096, links 2 (path: usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/__pycache__/msvccompiler.cpython-36.opt-1.pyc)
[  255.274012] [    T120] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711841792 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711841792, root 3133, inode 3313597, offset 0, length 4096, links 2 (path: usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/__pycache__/msvccompiler.cpython-36.pyc)
[  255.274687] [    T120] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711841792 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711841792, root 3125, inode 3313597, offset 0, length 4096, links 2 (path: usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/__pycache__/msvccompiler.cpython-36.opt-1.pyc)
[  255.274716] [    T120] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711841792 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711841792, root 3125, inode 3313597, offset 0, length 4096, links 2 (path: usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/__pycache__/msvccompiler.cpython-36.pyc)
[  255.275473] [    T120] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711841792 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711841792, root 3120, inode 3313597, offset 0, length 4096, links 2 (path: usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/__pycache__/msvccompiler.cpython-36.opt-1.pyc)
[  255.275498] [    T120] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711841792 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711841792, root 3120, inode 3313597, offset 0, length 4096, links 2 (path: usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/__pycache__/msvccompiler.cpython-36.pyc)
[  255.279788] [    T127] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711907328 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711907328, root 6977, inode 1523825, offset 34787328, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2021-06-09-wed/debug.log)
[  255.279818] [    T127] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711907328 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711907328, root 7033, inode 1523825, offset 34787328, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2021-06-09-wed/debug.log)
[  255.279839] [    T127] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711907328 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711907328, root 6990, inode 1523825, offset 34787328, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2021-06-09-wed/debug.log)
[  255.279856] [    T127] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711907328 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711907328, root 7032, inode 1523825, offset 34787328, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2021-06-09-wed/debug.log)
[  255.279873] [    T127] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711907328 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711907328, root 7026, inode 1523825, offset 34787328, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2021-06-09-wed/debug.log)
[  255.279889] [    T127] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711907328 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711907328, root 7025, inode 1523825, offset 34787328, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2021-06-09-wed/debug.log)
[  255.279904] [    T127] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711907328 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711907328, root 7024, inode 1523825, offset 34787328, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2021-06-09-wed/debug.log)
[  255.279920] [    T127] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711907328 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711907328, root 7023, inode 1523825, offset 34787328, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2021-06-09-wed/debug.log)
[  255.279936] [    T127] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711907328 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711907328, root 7022, inode 1523825, offset 34787328, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2021-06-09-wed/debug.log)
[  255.279959] [    T127] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711907328 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711907328, root 6979, inode 1523825, offset 34787328, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2021-06-09-wed/debug.log)
[  255.279977] [    T127] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711907328 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711907328, root 6991, inode 1523825, offset 34787328, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2021-06-09-wed/debug.log)
[  255.279996] [    T127] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711907328 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711907328, root 7021, inode 1523825, offset 34787328, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2021-06-09-wed/debug.log)
[  255.280029] [    T127] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711907328 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711907328, root 7020, inode 1523825, offset 34787328, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2021-06-09-wed/debug.log)
[  255.280045] [    T127] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711907328 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711907328, root 7029, inode 1523825, offset 34787328, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2021-06-09-wed/debug.log)
[  255.280051] [    T117] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4712366080 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4712366080, root 6977, inode 741045, offset 23760896, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2020-11-02-mon/debug.log)
[  255.280063] [    T127] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711907328 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711907328, root 7028, inode 1523825, offset 34787328, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2021-06-09-wed/debug.log)
[  255.280085] [    T127] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711907328 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711907328, root 6982, inode 1523825, offset 34787328, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2021-06-09-wed/debug.log)
[  255.280102] [    T127] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711907328 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711907328, root 7014, inode 1523825, offset 34787328, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2021-06-09-wed/debug.log)
[  255.280121] [    T127] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711907328 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711907328, root 7012, inode 1523825, offset 34787328, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2021-06-09-wed/debug.log)
[  255.280137] [    T127] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711907328 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711907328, root 6981, inode 1523825, offset 34787328, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2021-06-09-wed/debug.log)
[  255.280158] [    T127] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4711907328 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4711907328, root 6980, inode 1523825, offset 34787328, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2021-06-09-wed/debug.log)
[  255.280382] [    T117] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4712366080 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4712366080, root 7033, inode 741045, offset 23760896, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2020-11-02-mon/debug.log)
[  255.280408] [    T117] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4712366080 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4712366080, root 6990, inode 741045, offset 23760896, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2020-11-02-mon/debug.log)
[  255.280426] [    T117] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4712366080 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4712366080, root 7026, inode 741045, offset 23760896, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2020-11-02-mon/debug.log)
[  255.280442] [    T117] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4712366080 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4712366080, root 7025, inode 741045, offset 23760896, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2020-11-02-mon/debug.log)
[  255.280457] [    T117] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4712366080 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4712366080, root 7024, inode 741045, offset 23760896, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2020-11-02-mon/debug.log)
[  255.280474] [    T117] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4712366080 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4712366080, root 7023, inode 741045, offset 23760896, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2020-11-02-mon/debug.log)
[  255.280489] [    T117] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4712366080 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4712366080, root 7022, inode 741045, offset 23760896, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2020-11-02-mon/debug.log)
[  255.280506] [    T117] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4712366080 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4712366080, root 6979, inode 741045, offset 23760896, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2020-11-02-mon/debug.log)
[  255.280523] [    T117] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4712366080 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4712366080, root 6991, inode 741045, offset 23760896, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2020-11-02-mon/debug.log)
[  255.280540] [    T117] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4712366080 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4712366080, root 7021, inode 741045, offset 23760896, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2020-11-02-mon/debug.log)
[  255.280606] [    T117] BTRFS warning (device md126): checksum error at logical 4712366080 on dev /dev/md126, physical 4712366080, root 7032, inode 741045, offset 23760896, length 4096, links 1 (path: xfs/backup_log/srv/backups/backup-data/localhost/daily/2020-11-02-mon/debug.log)


There is no question in your "question". As "why?" is different than "how to fix?" or "is it safe to keep using the filesystem?", do not let us guess what your question is. Please [edit] and ask an explicit question.

Is it the name of directory by coincidence same as the name of other filesystem? Are you 100% sure the filesystem you work on is BTRFS and not XFS?

My btrfs was irrecoverably corrupted. I ended up just installing the OS from scratch and the problem went away. My data etc. was all fine as it was all on separate xfs file systems.
